# SQL new column count equal column-values

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I need your help!

```
count   Day         Title      Sum
1       02.10.2017  Urlaub     400
2       03.10.2017  Feiertag   400
2       03.10.2017  0          400
4       04.10.2017  11210      400
4       04.10.2017  11210      400
4       04.10.2017  0          400
4       04.10.2017  0          400
2       05.10.2017  0          400
2       05.10.2017  0          400
```

I need a resolution like the table above with an SQL-Query. It´s an MSSQL Server 2012. The SQL-Statement **Select * from Table** returns this:

```
Day         Title      Sum
02.10.2017  Urlaub     400
03.10.2017  Feiertag   400
03.10.2017  0          400
04.10.2017  11210      400
04.10.2017  11210      400
04.10.2017  0          400
04.10.2017  0          400
05.10.2017  0          400
05.10.2017  0          400
```

So I want to add the column count which represents the number of data sets where the column **Day** is equal.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

Comment: Show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Add your expected output format

Comment: SQL is a standard, so, please specify on which database you work too.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: It´s an MSSQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward to do with a windowed aggregate:

```
declare @t table (Day date not null, Title varchar(30) not null, Sum int not null)
insert into @t(Day,Title,Sum) values
('20171002','Urlaub',400),
('20171003','Feiertag',400),
('20171003','0',400),
('20171004','11210',400),
('20171004','11210',400),
('20171004','0',400),
('20171004','0',400),
('20171005','0',400),
('20171005','0',400)

select
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Day)
from
    @t
```

Result:

```
Day        Title                          Sum         
---------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----------
2017-10-02 Urlaub                         400         1
2017-10-03 Feiertag                       400         2
2017-10-03 0                              400         2
2017-10-04 11210                          400         4
2017-10-04 11210                          400         4
2017-10-04 0                              400         4
2017-10-04 0                              400         4
2017-10-05 0                              400         2
2017-10-05 0                              400         2
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered, however I will add my 2cents with an answer that does not use a window function but a correllated sub-query which should work across different DBMS

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(day) FROM YourTable WHERE day = t.day),
        day,
        title,
        sum     
FROM    YourTable t
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Window functions were added to the SQL Standard in 2003. It's sad that not all database products support them yet.

Comment: I love them. I was writing an answer with one in until you beat me to it ;)